# how to get products and images table from cart model

Tags: laravel, shopping-cart

How can I get This tree table with one query?

This is my products table

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->foreignId('subcategory_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This is images table

```
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('path');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And this is cart table

```
Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('session_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->integer('item_qty')->nullable(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This is how I get the table of products

```
$cartItems = Cart::with('product')
                        ->get();
```

But I can't get the table of images

Answer (score 1):

Product model

```
public function images()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Image', 'product_id');
}

$cartItems = Cart::with('product.images')->get();
```